# Send at Certain Send Time based on subscriber past attributes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I was wondering if it was possible to look at open times of subscribers in Marketing Cloud (It has this in the tracking reports (12/17/2018 9:08 AM) per subscriber with email and subscriber key) and do sending based on the time they're most likely to open their email? IS this available with the Einstein tool or another tool or a hack? I think if we start sending at more appropriate times, our open rates will increase.

Just wondering if anyone else has experience with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated Send-time Optimization was announced back in 2016, as being part of Einstein for marketing. However there is no indication of this feature being around the corner.

My suggestion will be to use Automation Studio and Query Activity to calculate most appropriate send time for subscribers based on Opens data view, and add the time stamp to a field on the sendable DE you will be using.

Then you can utilise Journey Builder [Wait by Attribute](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_by_attribute_example.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) feature, to have individual wait steps for the email send. After this step, you will just have the regular Email Send activity.

I know this requires some more work, but could be an interesting experiment to validate the effects of send time on your open rates. If there is significant difference, this might be worth the extra effort.